# How to log html link clicks to a text file

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, logging

Currently I am implementing a Java servlet web application. 
On a html page, users can find a lot of URL links.

I would like to record the click logs with time, a user's account name and clicked URL, onto a specific text file on the server.

I would like to know how to write a text onto a text file on the server.

Comment: You asked two questions here. Both are completely different. Besides that, what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Use `java.util.logging`. Aks google for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use logging in java using log4j [read more](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm)

If you click any link then pass some parameter that will identify your link at server side, Suppose when you click on link it will go to your servlet then get the parameter for that link and log it in file.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be helpful. But, how is it be invoked when a href link is clicked? If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

here is a complete example:

The href servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;


public class Log4JServlet extends HttpServlet {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4JServlet.class);

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = request.getParameter("url");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        log.info("info message " + url);
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Log4JInitServlet is initializing log4j");
        String log4jLocation = config.getInitParameter("log4j-properties-location");

        ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext();

        if (log4jLocation == null) {
            System.err.println("*** No log4j-properties-location init param, so initializing log4j with BasicConfigurator");
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
        } else {
            String webAppPath = sc.getRealPath("/");
            String log4jProp = webAppPath + log4jLocation;
            File logFile = new File(log4jProp);
            if (logFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Initializing log4j with: " + log4jProp);
                PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProp);
            } else {
                System.err.println("*** " + log4jProp + " file not found, so initializing log4j with BasicConfigurator");
                BasicConfigurator.configure();
            }
        }
        super.init(config);
    }
}
```

Then the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Log4JServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Log4JServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log4j-properties-location</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Log4JServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The log4j.property file:

```
# Set the root logger to DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,MonitorAppender

# MonitorLog - used to log messages in the Monitor.log file.
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.File=${catalina.base}/logs/MonitorLog.log
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

The index.html example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Link reporter</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $("body").delegate("a", "click", function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        reportUrl(url);
        //remove the line below, I just used it so it would be easier to debug
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function reportUrl(url) {
        $.get("/app/Log4JServlet", { url: url});
    }

</script>

<a href="test.html">test1</a>
<a href="test2.html">test2</a>
<a href="test3.html">test3</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically any link clicked on the index.html will be reported to the servlet and store the href to MonitorLog.log file placed in your tomcat logs folder.

I hope that helps

Comment: Why depend upon javascript for something so simple that can be done server-side only?

Comment: Hey @zack6849 thanks for the feedback. I interpreted "On a html page, users can find a lot of URL links." as a requirement, meaning Benben is looking to implement this framework in different html files and just log any link click. That's why I provided a simple js example that can be used anywhere he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are overcomplicating it, using third party libraries, etc, when none of it is necessary!

Here's some example code i've used for something similar, it logs all requests to a certain directory to a database, mainly just to keep track of which files are popular, but you could certainly switch this to flatfile logging

My code:

```
package com.zack6849.website.filters;

import com.zack6849.website.Database;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/uploads/*")
public class StatisticsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        System.out.printf("[STATS] request to %s", request.getRequestURI());
        if (request.getRequestURI() != null) {
            Database database = new Database();
            try {
                ResultSet count = database.query("SELECT COUNT (url) as results FROM requests WHERE url = ?", request.getRequestURI());
                boolean exists = count.getInt("results") > 0;
                count.close();
                if (!exists) {
                    database.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO requests (url, hits) VALUES (?, ?)", request.getRequestURI(), 0);
                }
                System.out.printf("[STATS] INCREMENTING 'hits' FOR %s", request.getRequestURI());
                database.executeUpdate("UPDATE requests SET hits = hits + 1  WHERE url = ?", request.getRequestURI());
                database.closeConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

Older servlet engines may require you to specify a filter for this in your web.xml, it should look something like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>logging</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.zack6849.website.filters.StatisticsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>logging</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploads/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```